# What does "author title" mean in a manuscript submission system?

Tags: authorship, titles

What does the author title mean in a manuscript application form? Does it mean {professor- assistant professor- lecturer} and if he/she isn't a university's staff what would the title be? Presuming he/she is master degree student in a medical specialty?

Comment: I don't know what a manuscript application form is specifically, but I would assume that if you don't hold a professional title, your title is simply Mr/Mrs/Ms etc.

Comment: the author's title when writing a research, medical paper or an article

Comment: Then I think you've answered your own question. As I said, if you don't hold a particular title (Professor, Doctor, Lord, Reverend, Captain, or whatever it may be) then your title is Mr/Mrs/Ms etc. As far as I know, a Masters degree doesn't confer any pre-nominal titles.

Answer (score 3):

If the author does not hold any of the usual academic tiles such as Dr/Prof./Asst. Prof. the status quo defaults to Mr/Ms/Mrs.